# $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}i\cdot \sin(x)\sin(2{\pi}kx)\;dx$ during Fourier transform

Tags: calculus, integration, fourier-analysis, complex-numbers

I am trying to do a time-to-frequency domain transform using Fourier transform. My function is very simple:
$$
f(x) = \sin(x)
$$
By definition its Fourier transform should be:
$$
F(k) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sin(x)e^{-2{\pi}ikx}\;dx \\
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sin(x)\left[\cos(2{\pi}kx)-i\cdot\sin(2{\pi}kx)\right]dx \\
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sin(x)\cos(2{\pi}kx)dx - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}i\cdot\sin(x)\sin(2{\pi}kx)dx \\
= 0 - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}i\cdot\sin(x)\sin(2{\pi}kx)dx
$$
Am I right so far? What's next? I couldn't calculate the term $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}i\cdot\sin(x)\sin(2{\pi}kx)dx$... I tried [integration by parts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts) but I still couldn't get it.

Answer (score 1):

The original integral doesn't converge. The Fourier transform $\mathscr F sin (k)$ gives us the coefficient of the basis element $e{^{i2\pi kx}}$.

Knowing that, is there a simpler way to do this?

Hint: Euler's identity